# How to enable arrows and space keys for scrolling, by clicking an element with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to disable the scroll when I click some div

```
  $('.whatever').click(function() {
      window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          // space and arrow keys
          if ([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      }, false);
  });
```

And now I would like to know How could I enable the scroll by clicking the same element again.

I'm looking for a kind of toogle effect (if you know what I mean), to enable and disable those keys for scrolling while clicking

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of using an anonymous function inside `window.addEventListener`, you can create a new, separate, named function.
2. Then you can use *that function* with `addEventListener`. After that, you can use a `boolean` in order to check the current state. When `click` happens, you can check this value, and either `add` or `remove` the `EventListener`.

```js
currentlyDisabled = false;

$('.whatever').click(function() {
  if (!currentlyDisabled) {
    currentlyDisabled = true;
    window.addEventListener("keydown", preventScroll);
  } else {
    currentlyDisabled = false;
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", preventScroll);
  }
});

function preventScroll(e) {
  // space and arrow keys
  if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="whatever">
  Click me!
</button>

<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
<p>Lots of paragraphs to show scrolling affect.</p>
```

Note: In order to see the effect, you may have to click inside the snippet result (as in on one of the paragraphs) and *then* try hitting the space bar.